Allow me to stay on a Staging Ground post after I submit a review action
Currently, if I am looking at a Staging Ground post and leave any review, I am immediately moved away to another post.
I do not want that. I want to stay at the post for a variety of reasons:

I might want to do something extra, like an edit, or to leave a comment.
I might just want to read the previous comments.
I might want to read the post and think about something.
I might simply not wish to go on to do another review.

I understand that Staging Ground is designed to work like the review queues, therefore the decision to immediately move way, like with other reviews. For this reason, I think moving to the next question should be optional and users should be able to opt-out or opt-in.
Here are some counter-points for why I do not think the Staging Ground is a review queue such that the behaviour should be mandatory and the only option:

Review queues, I have to explicitly go to. Staging Ground posts show interwined with any regular post, yet interacting with either is drastically different:


Even then, I can visit a list of Staging Ground items and pick and choose from the list. That is not the case with review queues. That is the case with regular question lists:


Review queues usually have one goal and one action you can take per review. In most cases it does not make sense to stay and look at a suggested edit after you have made any action. Nor stay and look at a a review from the Close votes queue after you have close voted or decided to leave open. And so on. With Staging Ground the idea is to take more of a holistic overview of the post and engage with the post author.

The Staging Ground supposedly tries to "Improve the engagement and knowledge transfer between new askers and reviewers". Moving me away at the first possibility seems to run counter to this goal.

"But you can do all the things you want and then post the review" OK. But I prefer to do the review first, instead of last.



Agreed. It shouldn't automatically move to the next one, at least not by default.

I agree mostly because of the "I might simply not wish to go on to do another review". Nuff said, it's an unnecessarily intrusive action. The rest read a little out of order doing them after the review and thus I find them not particularly strong arguments, but of course you do your process in your way.

@Gimby I had to add these because I mentioned "I don't like how SG moves away immediately after a review" in chat and even immediately defended why, yet I got a reply with "But that's how reviews work". Then another user brought up the same point that they don't want to be moved away and also immediately got told that's how review queues work. In both cases we know very well how review queues work but SG is not really the same as a review queue. Had I not went through the potential differences, I'd have likely already had a comment telling me that's how review queues work.

@Gimby also, it's important that if staff look at this they understand how users interact with SG. Because judging from decisions, actions, priorities - I'm not sure they know very well how the site is used.

During the beta, there was a lot of feedback from reviewers to staff including about the interactions with posts. But ig it's a bit of an issue that people beta-testing a feature like that are in some ways different from other people (and during the beta tests, it wasn't in the top questions page)

This was also discussed during the beta (link for people with access) but was marked as "status-deferred".

"Review queues, I have to explicitly go to. Staging Ground posts show interwined with any regular post" - my understanding is that this is not intended to be the long-term behaviour.

But rather than simply making SG not do all the standard queue things, I would like for the queues to stop being queues, and start doing all the other searching and filtering stuff that SG does.

Hum, I had already UV'ed this Qt 7 days ago when OP opened it, I just did my first Review today (thanks to this feat-req = status-completed, yeah...!!), but pfff, can I give a +2 to this Thread and [feat-req]...? This is really a blocking behaviour for me to do any more Reviews...! After doing an Edit to a SG-Post, of course I want to re-read/proofread my Edit and I don't want the "System"/Workkflow to jump to some completely random new Thread.... Stupid to have to use the Back Func from the Browser or to open all SG-Posts in a New Tab...

@chivracq if you use the Save without Review option, you get back to the post.

Oh, yep indeed, I "saw" that option @dan1st, => Thanks... // If I may ask a Qt, when doing an 'Edit', there is an option to post also the Edit Summary as Comment, does this Comment then count as the "obligatory Comment" for selecting 'Requires Major Changes'...? (Or do we have to post a separate Comment (that may repeat some parts from the Edit Summary)...?)

Yes, it should count AFAIK.


One more UV if I could, (now at +3...!), this is such an annoying and anti-quality behaviour...! Any Update from Staff...? I just gave today "a second try/chance" to SG, and pff, still the same, for my 2nd Review, I had to select a Duplicate, => land directly on some completely random different Thread, while I want to check the Status of my action, and post a Comment explaining to the Asker what they need to add to their Qt to prove if they (still) think it is not a Dupe. // Next try for SG for me in 1 week, ... or if I see a status_completed before for this Thread...


@chivracq I would spend all my daily votes on this if I could

Any way to start a riot to let Staff/Devs know that this random jumping to a next Thread after submitting a Review is completely useless...? Grrr..., this is so annoying...!

@chivracq To be honest, I like it moving to the next post and from what I have seen from other reviews, there are also other people liking that. If you don't, you can still use the "Return to questions" option.

@dan1st (thanks for following this Thread btw, you are doing a better job than Staff, ah-ah...!), yeah... beurk, I hate this random jumping to a new Thread without even being able to check my previous Action... Oh but so the Return to questions Button will still _Submit_ my Review, and will get me back to that specific Thread...? Sorry but "questions" (plural) is not very clear, I never tried that Button, but I would expect it to lead to the main SG View, with all Qt's (that I have already open in one Tab), and where the Qt I just reviewed is now lost "somewhere" on Page 2 or 3...

@chivracq You can use the "Return to questions" button to get to the SG questions list (/staging-ground) after  you submitted a review action. If you want to check on your reviewed question, you can use the link shown at the top after reviewing (though you don't need to in most cases unless you want to follow a published question or write another comment that shouldn't have the "Major Changes" marker. After submitting a review, you normally (i.e. in most cases) don't need to care about the question until the author edits it and submits it for Re-Evaluation.

@dan1st, yeah, but I already have a Tab open on the SG, I just want to get back to the specific Qt/Thread I just reviewed, which is now "lost somewhere" on Page 2-3-4 because the Status is not "New" anymore but "Major" or "Minor" (changes) and I need to load and try 2 of 3 pages with Ctrl+f + some keywords to finally find "my" Thread back...

@chivracq You can use the popup on the top of the question after reviewing (which contains a link to the reviewed question) or use your review history. With that, it's easy to get back to your reviewed questions. Alternatively, you can use the "Your reviewed posts" filter on the main Staging Ground questions page/list.

@dan1st, I don't know about which "popup on the top of the question" you are talking, as the Submit Button takes us directly to some random new Thread, but yes-yes-yes, this ?onlyMyReviews=true is a complete winner...! Wonderful...! (I pinned this Tab directly...!) How did you find it...?, it's not documented anywhere...?

@chivracq If you are on the Staging Ground questions list (You can get to it using "Return to questions" or using the "Staging Ground" link on the left), there is a "Review" history" button above the question list.

Oh..., I'm stupid, => "Show only my reviews" from the "Review history"... I could swear this switch was not there when I checked it once or twice 1 or 2 weeks ago... OK, good-good...!

For the popup, there should be a green box on the next question after you submitted the review telling you that you successfully dubmitted the review action and linking to the previous question. Anyways, you can join the Staging Ground Discussion/Support chatroom if you have any Staging-ground related questions.

Hum, OK for the popup, never noticed it, I'll pay attention "next time", but the 'My Reviews' Tab + Refresh will already/also do the job... That's a game changer... Thanks for that tip...

@dan1st, Thanks also for the Link to the Chat Room, excellent...!, as, a few times, I made a Review or posted a Comment, and I would have liked some Feedback from "some more experienced" Reviewer(s) if my action was correct...
